# Postgres SQL operator does not exist; character = integer;

Tags: postgresql

I am do replicating of two database (SQL Server 2000 and PostgreSQL). I use http://blog.hagander.net/archives/103-Replicating-from-MS-SQL-Server-to-PostgreSQL.html for this. Then I do last step the

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character = integer; Error executing the query
```

appeared. I use the PostgreSQL 8.4.6 for that and ODBC drivers (all psqlodbc_08_04_0100.zip, psqlodbc_08_04_0200.zip) from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) i also try to delete and install version that Synaptic called 9.0.2-1 and update odbc drivers i try (psqlodbc_09_00_0100.zip, psqlodbc_09_00_0101.zip, psqlodbc_09_00_0200.zip) it also return that error. The query launched from delphi where i use only System DSN runs normally

Comment: Please show us the executed and failing query from the postgresql logfile. I believe this is a setting in the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, but to debug this, I need the exact query done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to fix your SQL statement.

I bet you have something like

`WHERE character_column = 1`

and you need to change that to

`WHERE character_column = '1'`

Answer (score 0):

use `single quote` 'your_value' for non numeric data  and `double quote` for column name and never the opposite.

select status, sum(amount) as sum from "sales" where ("date" <= '2017-04-30 23:59:59' and "customer_id" = 1) and "sales"."deleted_at" is null group by "status"